# Is it possible to remove the internal control of lexer by the parser for parsing heredoc in shell?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, interpreter, flex-lexer

To deal with [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) in shell (e.g., bash), the grammar rule will change the variable `need_here_doc` via `push_heredoc()`.

```
    |   LESS_LESS WORD
            {
              source.dest = 0;
              redir.filename = $2;
              $$ = make_redirection (source, r_reading_until, redir, 0);
              push_heredoc ($$);
            }
```

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y#n539

```
static void
push_heredoc (r)
     REDIRECT *r;
{
  if (need_here_doc >= HEREDOC_MAX)
    {
      last_command_exit_value = EX_BADUSAGE;
      need_here_doc = 0;
      report_syntax_error (_("maximum here-document count exceeded"));
      reset_parser ();
      exit_shell (last_command_exit_value);
    }
  redir_stack[need_here_doc++] = r;
}
```

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y#n2794

`need_here_doc` is used in `read_token()`, which is called by `yylex()`. This makes the behavior of `yylex()` non-automomous.

Is it normal to design a parser that can change how `yylex()` behaves?

Is it because the shell language is not LALR(1), so there is no way to avoid changing the behavior of yylex() by the grammar actions?

```
      if (need_here_doc)
    gather_here_documents ();
```

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y#n3285

```
  current_token = read_token (READ);
```

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y#n2761

Answer (score 0):

> Is it normal to design a parser that can change how yylex() behaves?

Sure. It might not be ideal, but it's extremely common.

The Posix shell syntax is far from the ideal candidate for a flex/bison parser, and about the only thing you can say for the bash implementation using flex and bison is that it demonstrates how flexible those tools can be if pushed to their respective limits. Here-docs are not the only place where "lexical feedback" is necessary.

But even in more disciplined languages, lexical feedback can be useful. Or its alternative: writing partial parsing logic into the lexical scanner in order for it to know when the parse would require a different set of lexical rules.

Possibly the most well-known (or most frequently-commented) lexical feedback is the parsing of C-style cast expressions, which require the lexer to know whether the `foo` in `(foo)` is a typename or not. (This is usually implemented by way of a symbol table shared between the parser and the lexer but the precise implementation details are tricky.)

Here are a few other examples, which might be considered relatively benign uses of lexical feedback, although they certainly increase the coupling between lexer and parser.

- **Python** (and Haskell) require the lexical scanner to reformulate leading whitespace into INDENT or DEDENT tokens. But if the line break occurs within parentheses, the whitespace handling is suppressed (including the NEWLINE token itself).
- **Ecmascript** (Javascript) and other languages allow regular expression literals to be written surrounded by `/`s. But the `/` could also be a division operator or the first character in a `/=` mutation operator. The lexical decision depends on the parse context. (This could be guessed by the lexical scanner from the recent token history, which would count as reproducing part of the parsing logic in the lexical scanner.)
- Similar to the above, many languages overload `<` in ways which complicate the logic in the lexical scanner. The use as a template bracket rather than a comparison operator might be dealt with in the scanner -- in C++, for example, it will depend on features like whether the preceding identifier was a template or not -- but that doesn't actually change lexical context. However, the use of an angle bracket to indicate the start of an X/HTML literal (or template) definitely changes lexical context. As with the regex example above, it will be necessary to know whether or not a comparison operator would be syntactically valid or not.

> Is it because the shell language is not LALR(1), so there is no way to avoid changing the behavior of `yylex()` by the grammar actions?

The Posix shell syntax is most certainly not LALR(1), or even context-free. But most languages could not be parsed scannerlessly with an  LALR(1) parser, and many languages turn out not to have context-free grammars if you take all syntactic considerations into account. (Cf. C-style cast expressions, above.) Perhaps shell is further from the platonic ideal than most. But then, it grew over the years from a kernel intended to be simple to type, rather than formally analysable. (No comment from me about whether this excuse can be extended to Perl, which I don't plan to discuss here.)

What I'd say in general is that languages which embed other languages (regular expressions, HTML fragments, Flex/Bison semantic actions, shell arithmetic expansions, etc., etc.) present challenges for a simplistic parser/scanner model. Despite lots of interesting work and solid experimentation, my sense is that language embedding still lacks a good implementable formal structure. And since most languages do have embedded sublanguages, there is and will continue to be a certain adhockery in their parser implementations. In part, that's what makes this field of study so much fun.

Comment: Is bash’s implementation the best way to deal with such lexical feedback?

Comment: @user1424739: "best" is a loaded and subjective adjective. It's probably not how I would write a shell parser. But bash works just fine and is used by millions of people every day, which is more that can be said about anything I've ever written. A question I feel more comfortable with is "is the Posix shell syntax the best model for designing a programming language?", to which I would unhesitatingly respond "definitely not". If you're using bash as a source of ideas for writing your own parser, my advice would be to look elsewhere for examples.